# I can't shoot balls

Tags: idiomatic-language

I put away the basketball hoop.

My son asked me,

> "Where is the hoop. I can't shoot balls."
>
> "Where is the hoop. I can't shoot a ball."

Which one sounds natural? While speaking, do we use many balls or just one ball?

Comment: Shoot hoops is the idiomatic expression. Not shoot balls. Where's the hoop. I can't make the shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a figure of speech. "*I can't shoot balls*" doesn't mean that the speaker has many basketballs to shoot, but that's how the slang had been widely used.

Another commonly used lingo for playing basketball is **[Shooting hoops](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=shooting+hoops&oq=shooting+hoops&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2312j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**

Comment: +1. And in baseball, even if you have only one ball, you can still hit **hit some grounders** or **hit a few pops**.

Comment: I can't shoot balls is not idiomatic.